# looping through cascading combobox items in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, loops, cascading

There are three cascading combo boxes in a webpage. Say each one is having 3 items.
While loading the page, all are set to index zero. But the last (third combo box) has some values even the top two combo boxes are not changed. How the values changed are shown below.

Finally this webpage is loaded into the **web browser control in the vb.net**.
From the web browser the values are changed by firing the index changed event.

I have one more page in which there are 4 combo boxes which are also cascading one.

I have to get all possible values by looping all indexes changing in these two pages.

The no of combo boxes may vary page to page. I know the count, but I need one common method to retrieve all the possible values.

How to get the values of all combo boxes through a loop as shown below in generic way?

```
combo1             0
combo2             0
combo3             1
```

values should be in the form as given below

```
0   0   1
0   0   2
0   0   3
0   1   0
0   1   1
```

Comment: Which programming language are you referring to (please use proper tag)?

Answer (score 0):

The fact that they are logically cascading does not change how you traverse them. You are probably looking at storing their cascade order in an array:

```
Dim combos() As ComboBox = {combo1, combo2, combo3}
```

and then iterate via a `foreach` loop:

```
For Each combo As ComboBox in combos
  'do something
Next
```

It is not clear to me what you meant by `values should be in the form as given below`, so if you want a more specific answer, please elaborate on this last statement. Include some code and/or explain what those numbers are supposed to mean.

Comment: Please see, question is altered

Comment: @SateeshKumar: it's still not clear, now with even more details.